# changing a global variable in multiple defines - python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to change a global variable in multiple defines

here's my code:

```
x = 4

def thing_1():
 global x
 x += 1
 return x

def thing_2():
 x += 4
 return x

print(x)

thing_1()

print(x)

thing_2()

print(x)
```

I was expecting x to change each time... instead I got the error:
"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment"

Comment: You missed your `global x` call in `thing_2()`

Comment: So, while using `global` makes this work, you probably shouldn't be using `global`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at the **function thing_2()**  ,
the x there is local and you haven't define it before you increased its number.

if you want to change the global variable you must add **global x** at the beginning

```
def thing_2():
    global x
    x += 4
    return x
```